# i have error "no Session" in jpa-hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller

I try get data through jpa-hibernate, lazy join, but I got an error.
Here my stuff:

Table *user_role*

```
user_role_id    username    ROLE
2 petroff   ROLE_ADMIN
```

Table *user*

```
id  username    password    salt    email   profile phone   repassword 
 6 petroff     12345      ${config.salt}    petroff@еуые.com    test petroff prifile    ""  12345
```

Part class *User*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
@Repassword(pass = "password", repass = "repassword")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "salt")
    private String salt;
    @Email
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "profile")
    private String profile;
    private String repassword;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>();

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
```

Part class UserRole

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_role_id")
    private Integer userRoleId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private com.blog.blog.entity.User user;
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String role;

    //getter and setter methods
    public Integer getUserRoleId() {
        return userRoleId;
    }

    public void setUserRoleId(Integer userRoleId) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    }
```

call method

```
@Autowired
UserService us;

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {

        com.blog.blog.entity.User u = us.getByUserName("petroff");
        Set<UserRole> userRoles = u.getUserRole();
        return "hello";
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public User addUser(User u) {
        User savedUser = userRepository.saveAndFlush(u);
        return savedUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        userRepository.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User editUser(User u) {
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(u);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User getByUserName(String name) {
        return userRepository.findByUserName(name);
    }    
}
```

config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/config.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.blog.blog.service.impl"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.blog.blog.repositories"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.drivers}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.blog.blog.entity"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="userDetailsService"
          class="com.blog.blog.service.impl.UserDetailsImpl">
    </bean>
    <import resource="spring-security.xml"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
                      expression="execution(* com.blog.blog.service.impl.*Service.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut"/>

    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

I get User obj

```
 com.blog.blog.entity.User u = us.getByUserName("petroff");
```

but when i call

```
 Set<UserRole> userRoles = u.getUserRole();
```

i got an error:

```
Exception occurred in target VM: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.blog.blog.entity.User.userRole, could not initialize proxy - no Session 
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.blog.blog.entity.User.userRole, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:156)
    at com.blog.blog.controller.Main.printHello(Main.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to initialize lazy collection in the service if you want to use it on the caller side. Try this

```
@Override
public User getByUserName(String name) {
    User u = userRepository.findByUserName(name);
    Hibernate.initialize(u.getUserRole());
    return u;
}
```

There is plenty of discussions on this topic online, look it up if you want more background info on the subject.

Comment: Yes, i have tried this, and now i don't get error, but returned result  equal to "0"

Comment: Turn on SQL logging, and execute the generated query directly on the database to see if it returns any results. Also, post the code of `UserRepository#findByUserName(name)`, maybe that's where the problem is.

Comment: Info:   Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.email as email2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_, user0_.profile as profile4_1_, user0_.repassword as repasswo5_1_, user0_.salt as salt6_1_, user0_.username as username7_1_ from tbl_user user0_ where user0_.username=?
Info:   Hibernate: select userrole0_.username as username3_1_1_, userrole0_.user_role_id as user_rol1_2_1_, userrole0_.user_role_id as user_rol1_2_0_, userrole0_.role as role2_2_0_, userrole0_.username as username3_2_0_ from user_roles userrole0_ where userrole0_.username=?

Comment: ' public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
 
 @Query("select b from  User as b where b.username = :username")
 User findByUserName(@Param("username") String name);
 
}'

Comment: When you execute these SQL queries directly on your database, do you get any results?

Comment: Maybe =? is empty for user_roles.    User obj i  got correct.

Comment: yes if i use username 'petroff', i get result  `username3_1_1_ user_rol1_2_1_ user_rol1_2_0_ role2_2_0_ username3_2_0_
petroff 1 1 ROLE_USER petroff
`  `select userrole0_.username as username3_1_1_, userrole0_.user_role_id as user_rol1_2_1_, userrole0_.user_role_id as user_rol1_2_0_, userrole0_.role as role2_2_0_, userrole0_.username as username3_2_0_ from user_roles userrole0_ 
where userrole0_.username= 'petroff'`

Comment: The code looks OK, the query returns results, it all looks like it should work. Based on the information provided, I can't find anything that would cause the `u.getUserRole()` to return empty set.